# how to limit what the user writes in the console

Tags: c++, limit

How do I limit what the user types on the console?

Example: when he tries to write 1234 its okay and when he tries to write a character (a) or and word nothing happens and it is still 1234

so he can input numbers only

```
int main (){
int x;
cin>>x; // i want the x to take only numbers
cout<<x;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't. You just need to take whatever they give you and validate it if you need safety.

Comment: Unless you have specific hardware support (e.g. only provide a numeric keypad rather than a keyboard) there is no way to prevent a user entering non-numeric input.   A device that gives the user an electric shock on extending their finger toward a non-numeric character might discourage the user from entering bad input, but not prevent it.     The more conventional solution is to validate input, discard any bad input, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can read every single char your client is typing and treat it properly (a.k.a as you want). For example, if you want only integers as inputs, you can read them and if your user sends you a char you can send him back a message, you can block him from sending other inputs or you can just ignore the inputs you don't want.

```
int main () {
int x;
cin >> x; // i want the x to take only numbers
if(cin.fail()) {
    cout << "Invalid input" << endl; 
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't control what user types. In any case you should not rely on the validity of the input entered by user. The best approach would be to fetch input as a string, validate the input and then convert it to an integer.

```
// Check if each character entered in a digit
bool isValidString(string & inp)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inp.size(); i++)
    {
        // Checks whether inp[i] is a decimal digit character.
        if (!isdigit(inp[i]))
        {
            // This is not a digit.
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

In the main function:

```
int main()
{
    string inp;
    cin >> inp;
    int outputIntValue = 0;

    if (isValidString(inp))
    {
        // Converts the valid digits into integer 
        outputIntValue = atoi(inp.c_str());
        printf("Integer value: %d\n", outputIntValue );
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid input: %s\n", inp.c_str());
    }

    return 0;
}
```